# Installing Prettier on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I would like to use Prettier to format my code 'on save' but I am struggling to set it up.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. installed Prettier globally as node package using `npm install -g prettier`.
2. installed Prettier as VS Code extension.
3. In VSCode I went to file > preferences > settings: then searched for "Format On Save" and made sure that option was checked.

I understand that I now need to go to Visual Studio Code's 'User's settings/preferences' as JSON and put in the following configuration:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
// Enable per-language
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

The problem is, I can't find the "User's settings/preferences"?

If I go to 'file > preferences > settings' I don't see anywhere which will allow me to input java.

Answer (score 4):

## Install Prettier

Install the "Prettier - Code formatter" extension from the extensions sidebar.  Once this is complete, open a code file and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to auto format it.  You should see a prompt asking you to choose which 
code formatter you would like to use since you now have two available. Select Prettier from the prompt.

[image]
[image]

## Enable formatting on save for all files

Open the settings menu via "File > Preferences > Settings". Type `editor.formatonsave` into the search bar and enable the "Format On Save" setting.  Now, whenever you save any file it should be formatted automatically.

[image]

## Enable formatting on save for only certain file types

Open the `settings.json` file by navigating to "File > Preferences > Settings" and clicking the "Open Settings (JSON)" button at the top right of the screen.

[image]

Search the file for any preexisting `"editor.formatOnSave"` setting and delete it. Then add the following, replacing `"javascript"` with whatever language you want to enable format on save for.

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```